# How to run spring batch JSR 352

Tags: spring-batch, jsr352

May I know how to solve the following error? I run the spring batch based on the example in https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/jsr-352.html#jsr-352.

```
package com.example.springjsrdemo;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import javax.batch.operations.JobOperator;
import javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SpringJsrDemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JobOperator operator = BatchRuntime.getJobOperator();
    operator.start("job-batch-demo.xml", new Properties());
}
```

}

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                          http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                          http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/jobXML_1_0.xsd">

<!-- Job is defined using the JSL schema provided in JSR-352 -->
<job id="fooJob" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" version="1.0">
</job>
</beans>
```

I put the xml in resource/META-INF/batch-jobs

However i faced the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.batch.operations.JobOperator: Provider org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.launch.JsrJobOperator could not be instantiated
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime$1.run(BatchRuntime.java:52)
at javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime$1.run(BatchRuntime.java:47)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime.getJobOperator(BatchRuntime.java:47)
at com.example.springjsrdemo.SpringJsrDemoApplication.main(SpringJsrDemoApplication.java:19)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [jsrBaseContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1689)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1434)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:925)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
at org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext.<init>(GenericXmlApplicationContext.java:71)
at org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.launch.JsrJobOperator$BaseContextHolder.<init>(JsrJobOperator.java:831)
at org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.launch.JsrJobOperator$BaseContextHolder.getInstance(JsrJobOperator.java:839)
at org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.launch.JsrJobOperator.<init>(JsrJobOperator.java:163)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [jsrBaseContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:496)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
... 29 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:469)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1607)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1534)
... 35 more
```

May I know how to solve it? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that your application is not able to find the class `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource` in your classpath.

You need to add the jar that contains that class to your classpath. If you use Maven, adding the following dependency to your `pom.xml` file should solve the issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```